# Excel Graph Export is Blank

Tags: excel, vba

the purpose of the following code is to export a graph image to folder. It runs perfectly when using F8 step-by-step, but when executing normally the image comes blank. No error messages. Any ideas how to fix? any help much appreciated.

```
Sub ExportImage()

Dim sFilePath As String
Dim sView As String
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("chart$")
sFilePath = "C:\temp\Chart.png"

Sheet.Select
sView = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
zoom_coef = 100 / Sheet.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom

Set area = Sheet.Range(Sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
Set chartobj = Sheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
chartobj.Chart.Paste
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
chartobj.Chart.Export sFilePath, "png"
chartobj.Delete

ActiveWindow.View = sView

MsgBox ("Export completed! The file can be found here:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & sFilePath)

End Sub
```

[image: ![Output when doing step-by-step (F8)]
[image: output when running macro (f5)]

Comment: The code works for fine for me.Could you please paste a screenshot of your chart ?

Comment: thanks so much for takinng the time to look at code. I've added screenshots now. not sure it helps much though...